Analytics event notification_open is inaccurate
I am using firebase console to send push notifications to all the users by creating campaign in messaging section in firebase console. But the problem I am facing is, I can see notification_open count as 0, whereas it was sent to almost 8000 users. Please see attached screenshot as a reference.
